# Filling a 2D array with simple values. Indexing goes wrong

Tags: numpy, indexing, raster

I am filling a new raster layer for a QGIS plugin with values. To recreate the raster I am using Numpy arrays. In a loop I am filling the cells with new values. For this example I am using a place holder value, but that part is working fine. The indexing at the end of the code is where my problems occur. In this case only the last cell is filled with the value I want...

```
  for x1, y1 in np.ndenumerate(rast_int_newLU):
      for x2, y2 in np.ndenumerate(rast_int_oldLU):
          if x1 == x2:
             valueB = rast_int_oldLU[x1]
             valueA = rast_int_newLU[x2]

             dfkey = int(20)
             dt = np.float32

             a = np.ones(rast_int_oldLU.shape, dtype=dt)
             np.around(a, 4)
             indexx = x1[0]
             indexy = x1[1]
             a[indexx][indexy] = dfkey
      print("Output:")
      print(a)
```

Someone an idea where this goes wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the indexing goes wrong"? If there is an error message, please include it in the question.

Comment: Why is `a` created deep in the loop?

Comment: O damn, that is a classic mistake. When the array is created outside the loop everything works as intended! Thx for asking @hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

With help of @hpaulj I figured it out! It was a classic beginner mistake. The array was created inside the loop and thus resetting its default values back to 1. Only the last iteration this doesn't happen and so that cell wasn't converted back to 1. The correct code is:

```
dt = np.float32
a = np.ones(rast_int_oldLU.shape, dtype=dt)

for x1, y1 in np.ndenumerate(rast_int_newLU):
      for x2, y2 in np.ndenumerate(rast_int_oldLU):
          if x1 == x2:
             valueB = rast_int_oldLU[x1]
             valueA = rast_int_newLU[x2]

             dfkey = int(20)

             np.around(a, 4)
             indexx = x1[0]
             indexy = x1[1]
             a[indexx][indexy] = dfkey
      print("Output:")
      print(a)
```

Now all values are 20. Logically this value can be changed easily :)